# Angular 9 and .NET Core apps deployed under same folder on local IIS (This localhost page can’t be found)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting

I built my angular 9 application and published my asp.net core 3.1 application and copied all files under the deployment root folder and assigned it to http://localhost:5000

When I am trying to browse my website it gives error and can't navigate anywhere
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epgf1.png)

My asp.net core app startup configuration is:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^((?!.*?\b(web$.*|api\/.*)))((\w+))*\/?(\.\w{{5,}})?\??([^.]+)?$", "index.html", false));
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuth();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
    }
```

Just to mention that my API is working fine (All requests from fiddler or postman or another domain are succeeding and return values), and my angular build will work just fine if it is deployed alone with another site, Just my problem is that I am not redirected to my angular pages when deployed under same folder (I want it to work under the same folder)

Please if anyone can help me..

TO ADD:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

This is my program.cs hostbuilder might be useful for you

Comment: Did you set default startup page? Are you sure you have a page on that project. Did you enable directory browsing(IIS)? Try to annotate these two methods to see what the situation is. `app.UseRewriter()` and `app.UseHttpsRedirection()`.

Comment: @samwu - I have my index.html page of the angular app, i enabled directory browsing on IIS and i commented these two methods and nothing happened, still can't redirect anywhere in my site

Comment: @sawmu - I've added my host builder creator in my question above check if it might be helpful

Comment: Try to use failed request tracing to get detailed information of this error: [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).